# Install psycopg2 to a target directory on Linux

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 using pip's target switch:

In an empty directory on a new AWS EC2 instance, the following happens:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-25-10-192 ~]$ pip install -t psycopg2 .
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Processing /home/ec2-user
No files/directories in /tmp/pip-3SPtE_-build/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

Even if I upgrade pip, I get a similar error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-25-10-192 ~]$ /usr/local/bin/pip install -t psycopg2 .
Processing /home/ec2-user
No files/directories in /tmp/pip-DHJzs3-build/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

EDIT:

For reference, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install gcc; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python python-pip python-devel; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install postgresql-devel; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install zip; yum clean all

RUN pip install psycopg2 -t deploy/
RUN rm -f deploy.zip; zip -r deploy.zip deploy/*
```

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but I'm building a zip file to deploy to AWS Lambda.